# How can I create new recycle views starting from a different recycle view on another activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Can anyone explain to me how can I create a new recycle and add items to that recycle view staring from another recycle view inside another activity?

Basically, I want to create a shopping cart, for now, I retrieved the data from a Firebase dataset and displayed it inside a recycle view but now I would like to send this data to the shopping cart(the shopping cart is inside another activity), I'm able to send the data but I can't understand how to display the data inside the new recycle view of this new activity. I need this because I want to see the items that I added to the shopping list so then I can pay.

Below I will attach a photo to explain myself better.

My problem is that I can't understand how to add the sent data to a recycle view again in the new activity.

I'm new to Android, so it's the first time I'm doing this thing.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

My code:

**SearchItemsActivity:**

```java
    package com.example.ipill;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.nfc.Tag;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.Query;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;


    public class FirebaseSearch extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText mSearchField;
    private ImageButton mSearchBtn;
    private ImageButton AddToCart;
    private ImageButton Cart;

    String searchText="";

    private RecyclerView mResultList;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;




    private static ArrayList<Users> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int cart_count = 0;


    RecyclerView productRecyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebasesearch);

        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        mSearchField = findViewById(R.id.search_field);
        mSearchBtn   = findViewById(R.id.search_btn);
        mResultList  = findViewById(R.id.result_list_cart);
        AddToCart    = findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
        Cart         = findViewById(R.id.cartButton);

        mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mSearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                searchText = mSearchField.getText().toString();
                firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
            }
        });

        Cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            private Object Tag="Activity";

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cart_count < 1) {

                } else {
                    startActivity(new Intent(FirebaseSearch.this, CartActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });
     }



       private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {
        Toast.makeText(FirebaseSearch.this, "Started Search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Query firebaseSearchQuery = 
        mUserDatabase.orderByChild("Name").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new             
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(
                Users.class,
                R.layout.list_layout,
                UsersViewHolder.class,
                firebaseSearchQuery
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(UsersViewHolder viewHolder, Users model, int position) {
                viewHolder.getDetails(model.getName(), model.getSurname(),model.getPrice());
                viewHolder.setDetails(model.getName(), model.getSurname(),model.getPrice());
            }
        };
        mResultList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    // View Holder Class
    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        String nome;
        String surname;
        Long prezzo;

        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            ImageButton addToCart = (ImageButton)mView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    cart_count++;
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CartActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Name",nome);
                    intent.putExtra("Surname",surname);
                    intent.putExtra("Prezzo",Long.toString(prezzo));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        public void getDetails(String name,String cognome,Long price){
            nome=name;
            surname=cognome;
            prezzo=price;
        }


        public void setDetails(String name, String surname, Long price) {

            TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            TextView user_surname = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
            TextView user_price = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.price);

            user_name.setText(name);
            user_surname.setText(surname);
            user_price.setText(Long.toString(price));

            }
        }
    }
```

**The second activity where I receive the data and where I want to create the recycle view**

```java
       package com.example.ipill;

       import android.content.Context;
       import android.os.Build;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.util.Log;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.widget.Button;
       import android.widget.LinearLayout;
       import android.widget.TextView;
       import android.widget.Toast;
       import android.widget.Toolbar;
    
       import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
       import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
       import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
       import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

       import java.util.ArrayList;
       import java.util.Collection;
   

      public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       public static TextView grandTotal;
       public static int grandTotalplus;
       // create a temp list and add cartitem list
       public static ArrayList<Users> temparraylist;
       RecyclerView cartRecyclerView;

       Button proceedToBook;
       Context context;
       String name, surname, price;
       private static ArrayList<Users> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        context = this;
        temparraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        proceedToBook = findViewById(R.id.buyNow);
        grandTotal = findViewById(R.id.TotalPrice);

        cartRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cartList);

        String passedArg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Name");
        name = passedArg;


        String passedArg2 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Surname");
        surname = passedArg2;



        String passedArg3 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Price");
        price = passedArg3;

        System.out.println("DATA"+name+surname+price);

        cartRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        cartRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can re use the cart adapter just implement a recylerView into new Activity and make the cart adater object and set it into the new reyclerView and it done